# How do i get a hidden soft keyboard to show back up in WebView?

Tags: android, webview, keyboard, android-edittext

When the user presses the go button to navigate to a certain URL, the keyboard is hidden to go away. But when someone presses on an input field within the webview it's still gone. How do I make it come back for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not control keyboard in WebView input fields. But you can change layout/views of keyboard.
Here in keyboard we have options like Numeric, Characters, Symbol etc.